# Use of Handshaking Lemma to find number of subarrays with even Sum

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I was attempting to do practice questions and came across a solution I do not understand the reasoning behind.

The question can be found here, finding the number of even sum subarrays.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-number-subarrays-even-sum/

Questions related have been asked, but I am asking specifically about the use of the handshaking lemma at the end of the solution.

I understand that we build a count of the even and odd sum subarrays, but do not get why we use the hand shaking lemma to compute the number of even sum subarrays.  If we get a count of even and odd cumulative sums, how does the handshaking lemma exactly play into this?  Clearly, an even sum subarray is made of either odd + odd, even + even, or a lone even value, so I would just like to know how exactly all cases are being accounted for in this specific scenario. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we have an array of numbers, for example:

```
[1,3,5,2,10,7]
```

So, how to count the number of subarray with even sum?
Let's convert it into another array called `sum`, which the value at index `ith` is the sum of subarray from 0 to ith index

```
[1,4,9,11,21,28]
```

Clearly, we can see that for a subarray from range `a to b`, the sum of this subarray is even if and only if `sum[b] - sum[a - 1]` is even.

Now, let imagine that a graph connecting between odd and odd entry in `sum` and even and even in `sum` -> the number of edges in this graph is the answer for this problem.

So, from the handshake lemma, 2*E = sum of all vertexes degree

- The degree of each odd vertex is `number of odd vertex - 1`
- The degree of each even vertex is `number of even vertex - 1`

=> so

```
2*E = odd*(odd - 1) + even*(even - 1) => E = odd*(odd - 1)/ 2 + even*(even - 1)/2
```

Another way to understand this is for `odd` entries, the number of ways to choose `odd - odd` pairs is `C(odd, 2) = odd*(odd - 1)/2` with C is the [combination](http://www.mathwords.com/c/combination_formula.htm)

Comment: hi, thanks! I'm afraid I don't quite understand the two bullet points.  Why would we connect all odd/odd pairs and all even/even pairs even if they are not next to each other?

Comment: @user7090180 alright, let me try to explain in more details, stay tune

Comment: @user7090180 more explanation added.

Comment: Such a great explanation ..! Great job, But i have a doubt why does this handshaking lemma befit into this problem means how does this lemma ensures the count of even sum subarray?

Comment: Just a small note: Number of evens in the sum array should be initialized to 1 rather than 0. Because empty array has a sum of 0 (even) and for subarrays that start from the first element, 0 should be substracted. There is like an invisible even.