# count number of subarrays with odd sum

Tags: arrays, algorithm

```
Input : arr[] = {5, 4, 4, 5, 1, 3} 
Output : 12
```

Below is O(n^2) method by generating all the subarrays:-

```
These are possible subarrays with odd sum. 
1) {5} Sum = 5 (At index 0)
2) {5, 4}  Sum = 9
3) {5, 4, 4}  Sum = 13 
4) {5, 4, 4, 5, 1} Sum = 19
5) {4, 4, 5}  Sum = 13
6) {4, 4, 5, 1, 3}  Sum = 17
7) {4, 5}  Sum = 9 
8) {4, 5, 1, 3} Sum = 13
9) {5}  Sum = 5 (At index 3)
10) {5, 1, 3}  Sum = 9
11)  {1} Sum = 1
12) {3} Sum = 3
```

**But how to solve this in O(n)?**

Comment: there is a O(n) algorithm right there from where you pasted above content (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/number-of-subarrays-with-odd-sum/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of Handshaking Lemma to find number of subarrays with even Sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48495159/use-of-handshaking-lemma-to-find-number-of-subarrays-with-even-sum)

Comment: I know @SudhanshuVishnoi but I want to learn how that O(n) solution is working.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple solution in JAVA:

```
public class Odd {
  static int[] arr = { 5, 4, 4, 5, 1, 3 };

  public static void main(String... args) {
    int odd = 0;
    int even = 0;
    int result = 0;
    for (int i : arr) {
      if (i % 2 == 0) {
        even++;
      } else {
        int temp = even;
        even = odd;
        odd = temp + 1;
      }
      result += odd;
    }
    System.out.println(result);
  }

}
```

Here is the logic behind it:

We are going through all the elements of the array (that's why it will be O(n) ).
We have 3 helper variables. Result contains the number of all the counted sub-arrays. Odd ad even contains the odd/even subarrays which ends at the current position.

Each time we process the next element we increase the subarray-count by the array which could start at the given position.

So if the current element is an odd number we increase the odd counter otherwise the even counter.

Also if the current element is odd then we have to swap the number of odd/even counters because if we add the current - odd - number to a subbarray then it will change its parity.

And finally, add the number of current odd subarrays to the result variable - actually counting the odd subarrays which end at the current position.

Comment: I can't quite put my finger on it, but I have the feeling that there should be an O(1) solution with a math formula. After all, if you know how many odd and how many even numbers you have, you should be able to tell how many of those add up to either odd or even.

Comment: the order of odd/even numbers also matter. So you have to enumerate the elements anyway. Actually even if there would be a formula you still have to count the odd/even numbers and that will be o(n).

Comment: @ChatterOne There can't be an `O(1)` solution as that would mean you don't ever read the elements in the array